# Simple PHP APC progress bar

Tags: php, upload, apc, progress

I am currently working on one php upload progress bar that is using APC method.
More for this bar you can check here: http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/

Here is my upload.php code:

```
<?php 
$up_id = uniqid(); 
if ($_POST) {
//specify folder for file upload
$folder = "tmp/"; 
$redirect = "upload.php?success";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$folder" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
header('Location: '.$redirect); die;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Upload your file</title>
<link href="style_progress.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--display bar only if file is chosen-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
//show the progress bar only if a file field was clicked
    var show_bar = 0;
    $('input[type="file"]').click(function(){
        show_bar = 1;
    });
//show iframe on form submit
    $("#form1").submit(function(){

        if (show_bar === 1) { 
            $('#upload_frame').show();
            function set () {
                $('#upload_frame').attr('src','upload_frame.php?up_id=<?php echo $up_id; ?>');
            }
            setTimeout(set);
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload your file </h1>
<div>
  <?php if (isset($_GET['success'])) { ?>
  <span class="notice">Your file has been uploaded.</span>
  <?php } ?>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
    Choose a file to upload<br />
    <input type="hidden" name="APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS" id="progress_key" value="<?php echo $up_id; ?>"/>
    <input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="30"/>
    <br />
    <iframe id="upload_frame" name="upload_frame" frameborder="0" border="0" src="" scrolling="no" scrollbar="no" > </iframe>
    <br />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The upload_frame.php file code is the same as the original: http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/upload_frame.phps

Everything is working okey in this case and the progress bar is showing everything okey.

THE PROBLEM IS:
If i set in `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">` something for `action=""` like `action="upload_handler.php"` the upload progress bar is not working anymore.

So the question is how i can make this work with `action="upload_handler.php"` ?
Thanks in advance!